# Redirect an image to link

Tags: html, image, href, division, location-href

Good morning,

I would like to redirect when clicking on the image to a specific link.
In the corresponding code:

```
<div class="u-gallery-inner u-gallery-inner-1">
        <div class="u-effect-fade u-gallery-item">
          <div class="u-back-slide u-back-slide-1">
    
            <img class="u-back-image u-expanded u-back-image-1" src="/images/Imagensn/images2.jpg"> 
    
          </div>
         
          <div class="u-over-slide u-shading u-over-slide-1">
            <h3 class="u-gallery-heading"></h3>
            <p>Em breve</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply revise the `div` tag into `a`. The only thing need to notice is that `a` tag is an inline element by default.

Code sample below.

https://jsfiddle.net/bzuvqnjm/

Comment: Please include any code in the answer itself, as external services can disappear at any time, rendering the answer meaningless.